# Does bios lock prevent installing linux

Tags: linux, bios

I am considering buying used Lenovo ThinkPad T460S but it has locked BIOS. I have never used BIOS for anything so I don't expect this would cause any problems. The only thing I am worried about is that it might prevent me from installing Linux.
Is this something I should be worried about?

Comment: what does "locked BIOS" mean? what is locked? Besides, all laptops in the recent years use UEFI instead of BIOS, and none of the x86 laptops have locked bootloader, so you can always install another OS

Answer (score 1):

**No**, it will not prevent you from installing a Linux Distro on it. There are already several guides about installing linux on said laptop. Some sellers even sell it with Ubuntu pre-installed.

[Arch Linux Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lenovo_ThinkPad_T460s)

[Ubuntu Certification](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201512-20435/)

Comment: What I meant was more like whether it is possible that it will not allow me to boot from a flash drive because it has been disabled in the BIOS. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, that is possible.  Of-course, if its a used Thinkpad and the owner does not have the password is it stolen?

Comment: you can just reset bios in worst case.

Comment: No personal experience with the T460 but I have a Lenovo P50 (similar era) and I could make it boot from a flash drive to install Ubuntu. But if the BIOS is locked don't purchase the machine (admin BIOS password=>likely a "corporate" machine).